# How to load a memory layer into map canvas an zoom to it with pyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, buffer

I would like to load a vector memory layer into the map canvas with pyQGIS. Background is, I create a memory buffer layer around point data. While iterating the points I would like to visualize the buffer around each point in the map canvas and if possible automatically zoom to the memory layer. Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First makesure your mamory layer is added to the registry with

```
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(memorylayer)
```

Now you can activate your memory layer with

```
qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(memorylayer)
```

Now you can then zoom to the extents of that layer with

```
qgis.utils.iface.zoomToActiveLayer()
```